# Wie wächst Honig, oder was ist es überhaupt?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Die Frage kann schon merkwürdig klingen, aber lesen wir im 5. Buch Mose, Kapitel 8 (Luther 1912):

> 7 Denn der Herr, dein Gott, führt dich in ein gutes Land, ein Land, darin Bäche und Brunnen und Seen sind, die an den Bergen und in den Auen fließen; 8 ein Land, darin Weizen, Gerste, Weinstöcke, Feigenbäume und Granatäpfel sind; **ein Land darin Ölbäume und Honig wachsen**;

Ein einfache [Suche](https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/Deutsch/words/Honig) zeigt, dass Honig in der Bibel fast immer fließend ist (und wahrscheinlich sogar im denselben Land wo er wächst) mit der oben zitierten Ausnahme. Ist das ein "Ausrutscher" Luthers (den auch in ein paar anderen Übersetzungen übernommen wurde - "*ein Land, da Ölbäume und Honig innen wächset*") oder wird hier "Honig" tatsächlich in der Bedeutung benutzt, die heute etwas absurd klingt?

---

*In der englischen Übersetzung wächst der Honig nicht, also gehe ich davon aus, dass er im Original auch nicht wächst.*

> *For the Lord your God is bringing you into a good land, a land of brooks of water, of fountains and springs, flowing out in the valleys and hills, 8 a land of wheat and barley, of vines and fig trees and pomegranates, **a land of olive trees and honey***

Comment: Die Übersetzung wurde mittlerweile geändert in: ein Land, darin es Ölbäume und Honig gibt. Da haben sich ein paar Deutschlehrer beschwert, wie es aussieht. Aber solche Ausdrücke kommen schon mal vor: das Verb passt zum ersten Nomen und nicht zum zweiten. Den meisten Leuten ist das Jacke wie Hose.

Comment: For those English speakers following this, the *Buch Mose* is also known as "Deuteronomy". See [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bible_(King_James)/Deuteronomy).

Comment: Es gibt nicht "die" deutsche oder "die" englische Übersetzung. Mittlerweile gibt es in beiden Sprachen sicherlich schon jeweils an die 100 verschiedene Übersetzungen.

Comment: Zur Ergänzung von Hubert Schölnasts Kommentar: https://www.die-bibel.de/bibeln/wissen-zur-bibel/wissen-bibeluebersetzung/deutsche-bibeluebersetzungen-im-vergleich/

Comment: [Hier](https://www.e-rara.ch/zuz/doi/10.3931/e-rara-17064) kann man einen Bibeldruck aus dem Jahre 1531 einsehen. Den Vers findet man im pdf auf Seite 211. Leicht modernisiert: "Ein Land, da Ölbäum und Honig innen wächst". Das "innen" dürfte mit "da" zusammen gehören - "Ein Land, darin Ölbäum und Honig wächst".

Comment: Die Bedeutung von Honig ist doch nicht strittig, sondern die vom wachsen. Allerdings wachsen auch Sorgen oder Marzipanvorräte und bei Bienen wächst der Honig - nicht so, wie Pflanzen oder Tiere wachsen, aber es wachsen auch Dünen, wenn der Wind Sand aufschüttet oder der Trichter eines Vulkans, ganz unorganisch.

Comment: @userunknown ist schon klar, dass auch Sorgen oder Dünen oder Schulden wachsen können. Aber die Bäume, die neben dem Honig stehen, wirken auf die Deutung von "wachsen" (zumindest in meinem Kopf).

Answer (score 4):

Hier ist hebräische Originaltext: 5.Mose 8, 7-9
Den Satz, in dem von den Ölbäumen und dem Honig die Rede ist, habe ich fett markiert.

> ז כִּי יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ, מְבִיאֲךָ אֶל-אֶרֶץ טוֹבָה:  אֶרֶץ, נַחֲלֵי מָיִם--עֲיָנֹת וּתְהֹמֹת, יֹצְאִים בַּבִּקְעָה וּבָהָר.  **ח אֶרֶץ חִטָּה וּשְׂעֹרָה, וְגֶפֶן וּתְאֵנָה וְרִמּוֹן; אֶרֶץ-זֵית שֶׁמֶן, וּדְבָשׁ.**  ט אֶרֶץ, אֲשֶׁר לֹא בְמִסְכֵּנֻת תֹּאכַל-בָּהּ לֶחֶם--לֹא-תֶחְסַר כֹּל, בָּהּ; אֶרֶץ אֲשֶׁר אֲבָנֶיהָ בַרְזֶל, וּמֵהֲרָרֶיהָ תַּחְצֹב נְחֹשֶׁת.

In diesem fett hervorgehobenen Satz kommt gar kein Verb vor. Die deutsche Übersetzung dieses Satzes lautet eigentlich so:

> Land aus Weizen und Gerste und eine Rebe und eine Feige und ein Granatapfel; Land des Olivenöls und Honigs.

Wenn man das in eine germanische Sprache übersetzen will, muss man kreativ sein und irgend ein Verb erfinden, das in dieser Aufzählung einen Sinn ergibt.

Comment: Lutherbibel 1912.

Comment: @Hubert könntest du das Hebräische vielleicht erläutern & transliterieren? Mangels Kenntnis der Sprache kann das ja niemand nachvollziehen.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Nein, das kann ich nicht. Ich beherrsche nämlich leider weder Ivrit noch Hebräisch. Ich kann aber googeln und einzelne Wörter und Phrasen in Übersetzungsprogramme füttern. Damit kann man aber überraschend gut die Grammatik jeder beliebigen Sprache nachvollziehen. Ich habe auf dieselbe Weise übrigens auch rausgefunden, dass auch die meisten der 10 Gebote keine Verben enthalten. Insbesondere heißt es nirgendwo »Du sollst«. Beispielswiese besteht das Tötungsverbot aus nur zwei Wörtern: »Kein Mord.«

Comment: Den Text kann man [hier](https://www.bing.com/translator?cc=de) eintragen und erhält eine (vermutlich schlechte) Übersetzung: Land der Sünde und der Haare, Weinrebe und Feige und Widder; Olivenland, Öl und Honig. "Haare" steht sicher für Gerste mit ihren langen Grannen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Du hast vermutlich das [hier](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=hebr%C3%A4sich+%C3%BCberetszen) verwendet. Die Übersetzung ist besser, unterscheidet sich aber in Nuancen von "Olivenland, Öl und Honig".

Comment: In einem Text da ohne Punkt und Komma von Sätzen zu reden und dafür die ursprüngliche Passage sinnentstellend auseinander zu reißen ist frevelhaft (Verb: *bringt dich in [ein Land]*), dabei die Übersetzung zu bemühen, die gerade in Frage steht, ein fast unerträglicher Zirkelschluss. Der Interlinear Text (bspw. auf [bibelhub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/deuteronomy/8-8.htm)) lässt vielfältig Deutungen zu, etwa eine Anaphore auf Hettiter etc. Dafür sollte man aber etwas Hebräisch kennen, bloß nicht zu viel, sonst kann man *’e·reṣ ḥiṭ·ṭāh* nicht mehr als *ht* ([land von] Hittite) lese.

Comment: dazu passend wäre *ḏə·ḇāš* "Honig" ansatzweise auch als *devas* zu lesen.

Answer (score 4):

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wachsen) gibt als eine Bedeutung für wachsen, unter der Nummer 2a, an:

> entstehen, sich entwickeln

Und nach dem Abschnitt Etymologie ist diese Bedeutung schon im althochdeutschen *whasan* aus dem 8. Jahrhundert enthalten.

Ein Beispiel aus Dwds ist: *Der Brief wächst langsam*.

Im gleichen Sinn kann *Honig* wachsen, auch wenn das heute niemand mehr so formulieren würde. Aber an eine andere Bedeutung von Honig, nur um das wachsen im engeren Sinn auslegen zu können, glaube ich nicht, zumal auch dieses Wort schon sehr alt ist, [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Honig).

Comment: wenn hönig wächst wird er *wachsig*, ne?